# All users should redirect to new webpage if one user changed the database entry?

Tags: php, database, user-interface, phpmyadmin

Trying to make a multiplayer game of multiple choice question and rules are like that if the participant submitted the correct answer than all the participants will be redirected to the next question.
I am doing this using PHP.
My first approach towards it is making a javascript function that keeps on checking the database if the answer is solved or not but this seems to be quite time-consuming since for each participant thousand of the request going to be made to the database.
Is there any better way to do this?

Comment: You should post some code you have written and ask for specific help with the code. Read the tutorials about how to ask.

Answer (score -1):

You can try to use sockets:

http://php.net/manual/en/book.sockets.php

So the only machine that will query database will be the socket server.

You still need js script that will send request to socket server, however each request won't load the database.